# future clause confusion

Tags: future

Can I say:

> I will let you know what I manage to do

To express that after I manage to do something (in the future) I will write/talk with the recipient.

Comment: This is not a grammatical sentence. It is a question better suited to EL&U's sister site: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (English language for learners.) There are expert native and non-native users happy to explain and help improve your communication skills!

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks! this was my question here and I did not know if is suitable to be placed here. I will check ELL!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your first sentence *is* grammatical! Or did you mean "*That* is not a grammatical sentence."?! ;-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think it is grammatical, but is the meaning properly written...

Comment: @TrevorD what can I say? It's the heat, it's gone to *me* head. Well, someone has answered Fen. :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Or the Italian wine has gone to your head?! Thanks for all your contributions on here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say *I will let you know what I managed to do*

So sometime in the future I will contact you and tell you want I did in the interim